# android webview open the prevues page when I start the acivity

Tags: android, webview

I have been looking for a simple way to go to the prevues page when I start my webview activity instead of opening the main page every time I open the activity .

I tried to save the prevues page in the app but it didn't work.

Comment: if you have been looking for it what have you found so far? If you are asking someone to code for you this is the wrong place to ask for.

Comment: @Christian that is very strange, because I didn't find anything related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you you want the user to continue to browse from the last page he visited on.
to do so i will recommand to save the last URL (in the onPause method) with sharedPreferences.
when the user opens the app you will read the String from it and the default Value will be your home page.

in the first time the user opens the app it iwll enter him to the home page, after that, he will enter to the address that he left last time.

so:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("URL", MODE_PRIVATE);
String url = settings.getString("url", "http://www.tutorialspoint.com");
```

and you just need to enter the URL that you got:

```
browser.loadUrl(url);
```

in the onPause you will save the URL:

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString("url", browser.getUrl(););
 editor.commit();
```

keep in mind that you need access to the browser veriable so you need to put it outside the onCreate function

hope it will be helful and good night :)

Comment: thanks you got my point, I tried the code but it crashes my app. I will put what I did in my question.

Comment: no problem :) but please add the errors in the logCat so we will be able to see what is wrong